# Laptop will not resume from suspend if the charger is removed

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, acer, resume

I have seen this problem (or a similar one) with an older laptop a number of years ago.

If I suspend my laptop while connected to power, and then remove the charger, it will not be able to resume. I need to crash  the laptop and reboot.
Suspend works fine if it stays plugged in, as well as if I suspend it when the laptop is unplugged. Suspend also works if I suspend while it is unplugged, and plug it in. The only time it does not is if I unplug once it has already suspended.

Below are my current power centers
[image: My power settings currently]

Comment: Have you checked your battery state?

Comment: I have not, how would I go about this,?

Comment: Could you install `acpi` then run `acpi -i` and post here

Comment: Battery 0: Discharging, 97%, 04:37:03 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 2500 mAh, last full capacity 2360 mAh = 94%